# Use simd-json with reqwest

Tags: json, rust, serde, reqwest, serde-json

How can one get the Rust `reqwest` library to parse json via `simd-json`? I believe the current default is `serde_json`.

```rust
reqwest::get("https://www.example.com").await.json().await
```

If it is impossible, how does one make a web request and parse with simd-json, while avoiding the overhead of parsing to `.text()` and then parsing the string?

Comment: reqwest doesn't have native support for `simd-json`, it [always uses `serde_json`](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/blob/5397d2cf8eaecc9f964ab4d2b40b8f2ad24ce26d/Cargo.toml#L55).

Comment: Ok, how do you make a web request and parse with simd-json, without first parsing into a `String` and then parsing with simd-json?

Comment: use `.bytes()` if you want to avoid utf-8 validation

Comment: FYI, [this is exactly what `json()` does](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/src/reqwest/async_impl/response.rs.html#252-256).

Comment: You may be able to chunk it, but this is complicated because of async and I'm not sure it will help. simd-json may require full text anyway.

Comment: Why does reqwest use `serde_json`? My understanding is that `simd-json` faster in the majority of cases. Why isn't simd-json the default? Am I missing a tradeoff?

Comment: @Test simd-json requires CPU SIMD support for the better performance. You can configure it to use a software fallback for SIMD, but that's probably slower than serde_json. serde_json is also more widely used in the Rust ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but highlighting Chayim Friedman's insight that reqwest already fully downloads the body into `.bytes()` before parsing it.